# Code First - Repository Pattern - Design Considerations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, architecture, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I am trying to make a Repository+UnitOfWork platform. My IRepository interface looks like below.

```
 public interface IRepository<TEntity>
        where TEntity : IEntity
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll();
        TEntity Get(int id);
        IQueryable<TEntity> FindBy(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate);
        TEntity Add(TEntity entity);
        TEntity Delete(TEntity entity);
        void Save(TEntity entity);
    }
```

I am confused about some questions as follows...

1. The IEntity which are handled in the interface are code first entities (not business objects). Is ideally a Repository expected to handle (accept+return) them or the business objects itself?
2. Should a Repository return IQueryable or IEnumerable?
3. If the answer for the Question #1 is business object, then how to
   implement mapping between Entities and Business objects?
4. If I introduce a new service layer (which will be
   consumed by the client), the service layer will be the once which calls the Repository methods, and mapping. Is this correct?
5. If the answer to the above question is yes, then doing mapping in
   service layer breaks Single Responsibility Principle. How to get
   over it?

I also welcome a link for a sample application (MVC,EF,SQL Server) with Repository and UnitOfWork implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no right or wrong in software design, but within my knowledge, there are some design practices that can answer your question.

> The IEntity which are handled in the interface are code first entities
>   (not business objects). Is ideally a Repository expected to handle
>   (accept+return) them or the business objects itself?

- Ideally, repository layer should only deal with entity objects. Don't flood it with business objects & mapping logics

> Should a Repository return IQueryable or IEnumerable?

- I would prefer to use `Iqueryable`, because `Iqueryable` also inherits from `IEnumerable`, so every thing `IEnumerable` can do, `IQueryable` can do too. More importantly, every query attemps with `Iqueryable` will be executed in `database` layer. So in conclusion, if you're not sure if you still need to perform any extra query (for example: filtering data), `IQueryable` is absolutely a must.

> If the answer for the Question #1 is business object, then how to
>   implement mapping between Entities and Business objects?

- There're a lot of ways of doing mapping, `AutoMapper` is a good and stable library for that purpose.

> If I introduce a new service layer (which will be consumed by the
>   client), the service layer will be the once which calls the Repository
>   methods, and mapping. Is this correct?

- It really depends on how you design your **service layer**. Usual flow is:

  call `Repository` methods => get data => map to business object => perform extra logics => return business object

> If the answer to the above question is yes, then doing mapping in
>   service layer breaks Single Responsibility Principle. How to get over
>   it?

as in the definition of Single Responsibility Principle (**A class should have only one reason to change**), your service layer responsiblity is to perform extra logics on the business object, so I would say it woult not violate SRP.

```
public SampleDTO SampleServiceMethod(InputModel input)
{
    var model = _sampleRepository.FindBy(input.Id);

    var dto = SampleMapper.ToSampleDto(model);

    // do something and return the dto
    dto.Test = 1;

    return dto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> 1. The IEntity which are handled in the interface are code first entities (not business objects). Is ideally a Repository expected to handle (accept+return) them or the business objects itself?

Do you have any reason to have separate domain model (business objects) and persistence model (code-first entities)? EF doesn't have many extra requirements for code-first classes, usually you can just persist your business objects directly.

If you choose to have a separate persistence model, then it should be an implementation detail of the repositories. The repositories should work with business objects.

> 2. Should a Repository return IQueryable or IEnumerable?

It depends. `IQueryable` makes it easy to create queries in application layer without modifying the repository. It's especially useful in CQRS, when you have a separate simple read stack.

You have to be aware that using `IQueryable` introduces a dependency on the underlying data source. A query that works with one data source might fail at runtime when you change the data source.

> 3. If the answer for the Question #1 is business object, then how to implement mapping between Entities and Business objects?

You can use a tool like [Automapper](http://automapper.org/).

> 4. If I introduce a new service layer (which will be consumed by the client), the service layer will be the once which calls the Repository methods, and mapping. Is this correct?

The service layer will call the repository. The repository will return/add/modify a business object. Any mapping (if necessary) will be done within the repository.